# Вложенные классы в AIDL

Tags: java, android, aidl

Есть класс в котором есть вложенные static классы. Как это все можно представить в aidl? То есть грубо говоря как мне передать в удалённую функцию объект Outter.Inner?

```
class Outter implements Parcelable {

    public static class Inner {

    }

}
```